# which one of the drivers have their implementation in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

In Java we have four types of drivers where type 3 and 4 both are written in java,but if we have to choose any one of the driver then which one of the driver we should go with ? will it be type 3 or type 4?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-driver-types.htm

Comment: Thank you for the link, but the thing is that both driver type 3 and 4 are written completely in java and i have to go with one. Then what can be the closest answer to this question?

Comment: You need to actually read the document, it quite literally guides you on which to select

Comment: hmm..okay....but sorry for this, but after reading so many documents i have this confusion. i referred many articles where i found the same that creates confusion.

Comment: "If you are accessing one type of database, such as Oracle, Sybase, or IBM, the preferred driver type is 4.

If your Java application is accessing multiple types of databases at the same time, type 3 is the preferred driver." - from Tibrogargan's link. I don't think you can get it more clearly. Now which of those is the case in your project? Do you have to go for one single specific database system or do you need the flexibility to be able to use various DBMS? The answer to that question will be the answer to your question.

Comment: All JDBC driver types are written in Java, even type 1 and type 2, but type 1 delegates to an ODBC driver and type 2 delegates things to the native database driver. I have only seen a type 3 driver once, afaik they are not very common.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pointless. You don't have any choice about it. You have to use whatever driver type the vendor of your database chose to implement, and they're not so silly as to implement all the available types when one would do.

It's the *vendor* who has this choice. Not you. In practice you will almost certainly find that the vendor has implemented type 4.

Answer (score -2):

The Type 3 and type 4 java drivers are written by the database vendor in jar file which is called jdbc driver like in oracle ojdbc5.jar in mysql mysql-connector.jar.
Jars are available with the database where you installed the database.
For implementation details please check inside your database where you installed the database in jdbc folder or you can downlaod from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/tags/jdbc) and search for relevant database driver,download it extract it and see what you want to see.
I hope this will help you for growing your knowledge and don't forget to share with another what you have.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: well, first of all thanks for this informative answer , now-a -days type  4 driver is used but we can also use type 3 instead of type-4 , both are giving the java implementation , so what can be the closest answer to this question in terms of choosing any one driver giving java implementation out of two?

Comment: it depends on your requirement if your application interact with multiple database then you should chose type 3,if any specfic database like oracle,mysql,DB2 then you choose type 4.

Comment: I think you mean type 2 and type 4, as type 3 is a 'middleware' driver and most vendors only provide type 4 and maybe a type 2.

Comment: every vendor provide type 3 and type 4 driver.actually type 1 and type 2 is deprecated from 1.6 version both are comes under java package till 1.5 or may be in 1.6(i am not sure about version),so do not use it is not recommended.

Comment: No, only type 1 (the JDBC-ODBC bridge) was removed in Java 8. The type 2  is very much alive (eg the Oracle OCI JDBC support) and it is vendor specific (they have never "come[s] under java package", whatever that means). As I said I have hardly ever seen a type 3 driver in the wild; they are pretty rare AFAIK. Type 4 is most common, followed by Type 2.

Comment: @sudhanshu160393 Every vendor does *not* provide both a type 3 and type 4 driver. If you have some evidence to the contrary please provide it. MySQL for example provides exactly one JDBC driver and [it is type 4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-overview.html). And you haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: There are some exceptional case which i am not aware.Thanks for giving this information.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say there are some exceptional cases you *are* aware of, such as (maybe) Oracle. Why in general would a vendor provide both types? You shouldn't generalize without evidence.